# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'table_name.id'

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I am new in laravel, for user login and registration I have created my own table named as 'provider_regs' which contains auto_id as a primary key (provider_regs table doesn't contain any key named as 'id'). After successful registration when I try to hit the same registration url in another tab then I am getting the following error page:

SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'provider_regs.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `provider_regs` where `provider_regs`.`id` = 0 limit 1)

and when I do clear history then it won't show me that error page. I don't know what to do, Please give any suggestion.

Comment: can you paste your laravel query here?

Comment: I got these queries on the error page,                                                            
at Connection->runQueryCallback('select * from `provider_regs` where `provider_regs`.`id` = ? limit 1', array('0'), object(Closure)) in Connection.php line 596
at Connection->run('select * from `provider_regs` where `provider_regs`.`id` = ? limit 1', array('0'), object(Closure)) in Connection.php line 315
at Connection->select('select * from `provider_regs` where `provider_regs`.`id` = ? limit 1', array('0'), true) in Builder.php line 1389

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `ProviderRegs` model you may change the primary key, because the default is `id`, and you would like to use `auto_id`.

Add `$primaryKey` variable to your model *(App\ProviderRegs.php)*:

```
class ProviderRegs extends Model {
    protected $primaryKey = 'auto_id';
}
```

> Eloquent will also assume that each table has a primary key column
>   named id. You may define a `$primaryKey` property to override this
>   convention.